# Mitsubishi Outlander extended crank

Tags: starting, fuel-system, ignition

Why would I have an extended crank after replacing all of my injectors and also have rich bank 1&2 codes? Have double checked timing and vacuum,all seems ok. If I shut it off and start it right back up it starts fine. I did not have these problems before. Could I have gotten bad injectors?

Comment: Welcome to the site, what do you mean by 'extended crank?' Do you have any codes?

Comment: It sounds like you have leaking injectors.

Comment: I bought cheap injectors off rock auto, could this be a common problem ?